# Tree-reweighted belief propagation: optimizing edge appearances $\mu$

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, constrained-optimization, variational-inference, belief-propagation

I am currently implementing Tree-Reweighted Belief Propagation (TRBP) to optimize edge appearances. The authors in the main manuscript of this work keep the edge appearances, represented by , fixed [1]. However, in their previous research, they introduce a tighter bound that allows the problem to be framed over all spanning trees, creating a connection to the Bethe Free energy. They formulate the optimization problem as a max-min problem, where  represents the edge appearances. This involves a min optimization step similar to BP that involves message passing, as well as a max step that maximizes  to select the best spanning tree.

The log partition approximation is as follows:

\begin{align*}
    \Phi(\theta^*)\leq -\max_{\boldsymbol{\mu}\in \mathbb{T}(G)}\min_{\boldsymbol{T}\in \mathbb{C}} \mathcal{H}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{T};\theta^*)=&-\max_{\boldsymbol{\mu}\in \mathbb{T}(G)}\min_{\boldsymbol{T}\in \mathbb{C}}-\sum_{s\in V}H_s(T_s)+\sum_{(s,t)\in E}\mu_{st}I_{st}(T_{st})-\boldsymbol{T}^\intercal\boldsymbol{\theta}^*
\end{align*}

Here, $\boldsymbol{T}$ represents the beliefs obtained from message passing using a BP-like approach, and $\mu$ represents the edge appearances that are constrained to be within the spanning tree polytope $\mathbb{T}$. The spanning tree polytope utilizes a distribution over spanning trees $\mu(\mathcal{T})$. However, for TRBP, it suffices to optimize over a vector of edge appearances.

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{T}(G) =& \{\mu_i = \mathbb{E}_{\mu(\mathcal{T})}\delta[i\in\mathcal{T}]; \forall i\in E; \sum_\mathcal{T}^\Im\mu(\mathcal{T})=1\}
\end{align*}

The tree-spanning polytope can be characterized in terms of linear properties for a given $G=(V,E)$.

1. $\sum_{i\in F} \mu_i \leq r(F) = v(F)-c(F), \text{ where } F\subseteq E$
2. $\sum_{i \in E} \mu_i = n-1$
3. $\mu_i\geq 0$

Now, the question arises: how do they maximize $\mu$ in this context? In the original paper [2; algorithm 1], they suggest using conditional gradient ascent, which involves using the mutual information as the gradient of the approximation. The maximization can be translated into running Kruskal's algorithm on the mutual information to obtain the best spanning tree.

I am a bit confused about the maximization step and how to perform constrained optimization to guarantee that the edge appearances belong to the spanning tree polytope $\mu \in \mathcal{T}$. Especially, because the first constraint is exponential as it needs all the subsets $F$.

To summarize the algorithm:

1. Initialize  with an initial guess.
2. Use TRBP to obtain the beliefs .
3. Calculate the gradient of the log partition approximation with respect to , which is the mutual information.

- do they run here Kruskal's algorithm and update only edges that maximize a spanning tree?

4. Update  by taking a step towards the gradient ascent.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until convergence.

---

1. Tree-reweighted belief propagation algorithms and approximate ML estimation by pseudo-moment matching http://proceedings.mlr.press/r4/wainwright03a/wainwright03a.pdf
2. A New Class of Upper Bounds on the Log Partition Function
   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0610.pdf